# Can I define a transformation between 2D and 3D in Geotools?

Tags: georeferencing, 3d, coordinate-system, geotools

I'm using Geotools, and I need to convert coordinates between 2D and 3D coordinate reference systems.  I recognize that there's no universally-correct way to do this:  2D -> 3D means "making up" a Z coordinate, and 3D -> 2D means losing information.  But, is there some way to teach Geotools that, in my particular context, I want to use a specific transformation.  E.g.:

```
+-----+                 +-----+
|     | --- Z = 15 ---> |     |
| 2D  |                 |  3D |
|     | <-- drop Z ---- |     |
+-----+                 +-----+
```

I know I can transform any particular coordinate manually this way, but I'd like to  integrate it so this Just Works.  e.g. I can do `CRS.findMathTranform(a, b)` and if `a` is convertible to my 2D CRS, and my 3D CRS is convertible to `b`, it works.

Comment: Was my answer acceptable? Do you mind letting us know by “accepting” it (i.e., click the ✔ check) and “upvoting” (click the Λ arrow)? Cheers.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but in this case it didn't really solve the problem.  Thanks, though!

Answer (score 1):

I can speak to "coordinate transformation" issue, but not to any Geotools detail.

When transforming between 2D and 3D coordinates, the two systems are often either known to be or assumed to be parallel. Thus, there should be no problem: assign or drop your Z values as needed.

(Maybe you already know that and need the Geotools details that i cannot provide.)