# Defining coordinate reference system with rotation in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, coordinate-system, geotools

I am using GeoServer and have a layer in `EPSG:900913` ("Google Mercator").

I need to "rotate" the map around certain point (say, `1500000, 7000000`) by certain degree (say, 30 degrees clockwise). How could I define such a coordinate system based on `EPSG:900913`?

GeoServer's [`angle` vendor option](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html#angle) does not work for my purposes as I need to tile the map later on.

As far as I understand this, my only option is to define an own coordinate system. For GeoServer I'd need to [define it in WKT form](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/advanced/crshandling/customcrs.html). The configuration seems to be straightforward, but I have a difficulty defining my rotated CRS in [WKT](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/opengis/referencing/doc-files/WKT.html).

I am wondering how to apply a rotation around certain point onto a CRS like Google Mercator:

```
PROJCS["WGS84 / Google Mercator", 
  GEOGCS["WGS 84", 
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", 
      SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], 
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], 
    PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
    UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
    AXIS["Longitude", EAST], 
    AXIS["Latitude", NORTH], 
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]], 
  PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"], 
  PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6378137.0], 
  PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["central_meridian", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["scale_factor", 1.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_easting", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0], 
  UNIT["m", 1.0], 
  AXIS["x", EAST], 
  AXIS["y", NORTH], 
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","900913"]]
```

My questions, specifically:

- How to write a WKT which transform an existing CRS? My guess would be that I need a new `PROJCS` wrapping an existing one and adding a `PROJECTION` clause.
- How would I found out the projection id (like `Mercator_1SP` above) and the required parameters (the `PARAMETER` clauses)?
- Can I "reference" `EPSG:900913` in CRS WKT instead of copy-pasting the whole `PROJCS` clause?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I've figured it out.

It is possible to apply an affine transform onto some existing CRS using `FITTED_CS`. Below is an example of rotation of 60 degrees counterclockwise and movement:

```
FITTED_CS["BPAF", 
  PARAM_MT["Affine", 
    PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
    PARAMETER["num_col", 3], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_0", -0.5], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_1", -0.8660254037844386], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_2", 1487816.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_0", 0.8660254037844386], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_1", -0.5], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_2", 6886579.0]], 
  PROJCS["WGS84 / Google Mercator", 
    GEOGCS["WGS 84", 
      DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", 
        SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], 
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], 
      PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
      UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
      AXIS["Longitude", EAST], 
      AXIS["Latitude", NORTH], 
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]], 
    PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"], 
    PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6378137.0], 
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
    PARAMETER["central_meridian", 0.0], 
    PARAMETER["scale_factor", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["false_easting", 0.0], 
    PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0], 
    UNIT["m", 1.0], 
    AXIS["x", EAST], 
    AXIS["y", NORTH], 
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","900913"]], 
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","8011113"]]
```

However I've found a bug in the current version of GeoTools (class cast exception when parsing this WKT). I've patched it and will also commit the fix.

Comment: OMG that's mental, trying it now.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a local rotated coordinate sytem as I explained here:

[Using customized Coordinate System in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83861/using-customized-coordinate-system-for-archaeological-site-data)

Center point and rotation have to be defined in degrees.

Your idea of wrapping one projection with another is not defined in PROJ.4. You can try it out, but don't expect it to work.

Comment: since GeoServer doesn't use Proj.4 that should not be a problem for the OP