# How do I rotate a coordinate system (ArcGIS/GDAL driver)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, gdal, tile-map-service, mosaic-dataset

I am trying to get oblique tiles into a mosaic dataset. The tiling scheme works perfectly well for vertical and north imagery (using google tiling scheme) through the GDAL driver, however I am struggling to get 45 degree tiles in.

The tiles are indexed very similarly to google tiles (starting at top left) as per example below (East orientation):

[image]

The crux of the problem is the CRS as defined by the GDAL XML. This is what it looks like for vertical imagery:

`<GDAL_WMS>
<Service name="TMS">
<ServerUrl>http://example.com?x=${x}&amp;y=${y}&amp;z=${z}</ServerUrl>
</Service>
<DataWindow>
<UpperLeftX>12523442.7125</UpperLeftX>
<UpperLeftY>-1878516.40687</UpperLeftY>
<LowerRightX>13149614.8481</LowerRightX>
<LowerRightY>-2504688.5425</LowerRightY>
<TileLevel>21</TileLevel>
<SizeX>8388608</SizeX>
<SizeY>8388608</SizeY>
<TileX>1703936</TileX>
<TileY>1146880</TileY>
<YOrigin>top</YOrigin>
</DataWindow>
<Projection>PROJCS["WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],AXIS["Lat",SOUTH],AXIS["Long",EAST]],PROJECTION["Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",0.0],PARAMETER["Auxiliary_Sphere_Type",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0],AUTHORITY["EPSG",3857]]</Projection>
<BlockSizeX>256</BlockSizeX>
<BlockSizeY>256</BlockSizeY>
<BandsCount>3</BandsCount>
<UnsafeSSL>true</UnsafeSSL>
<MaxConnections>10</MaxConnections>
</GDAL_WMS>`

My theory is that I need to rotate the coordinate system so that, in the example of East orientation, Y axis gots towards East, and X axis goes towards South. After trying a few things I could not get it to work. The best candidate was an affine transform as described here https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/159134/52713, however that just resulted in an invalid dataset (using identity transform or no-op transform), showing up in ArcMap like so:

[image]

Comment: how are the tiles oblique? Is it a rotated rectangular image or nodata filled. All images *must* be rectangular but can be rotated or filled... generating seamlines on a raster dataset might help.

Comment: The tiles are square. The are "oblique" because they were taken at an angle and then chopped up into tiles. Depending on the orientation, a different compass point is at the top edge of the tile as per the diagram in the question.

Comment: Can you show what one tile looks like.. what format are they in? is there a world file to show the parameters? I suspect that your tiles contain all data but have rotation coefficients in their georeference.. In the *old* days we would Rectify these images which fills in the rest of the rectangle by adding nodata because ArcINFO couldn't display a rotated image. You should be able to Affine the extents using the world file https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file if you export to world tiff (gdal_translate with TFW=YES parameter).

Comment: Why not rotate them by -90 in  batch using spatial analyst?

Comment: @FelixIP Rotating the tiles is not really feasible due to the scale and we want them to be in that orientation so that they can be displayed in a web client without the need to rotate them.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I don't have a world file. I can have a go hand crafting it, but it requires a projection, which I don't have, which is also the question that I am asking.

Comment: Not really, if the tiles are georeferenced the coordinates are specified as a 6 parameter transformation (affine), spatial reference is something else entirely. It only becomes a problem of spatial reference if you've got the tiles (rectangular) in one spatial reference but want to see them in a different spatial reference, if that's the case create the boxes in the native spatial reference, densify and project the boxes. Try one and see what you get.

Comment: Now that you have experimented with doing this using GDAL and ArcMap, I think you should reduce the scope of your question to one, the other, or to some other GIS product to try and entice potential answerers to provide one.