# Displaying rotated grid data in Leaflet with GeoServer WMS

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver, leaflet, wms, netcdf

I am trying to display rotated grid data from NetCDF in Leaflet.
When I try to use the "WMS angle parameter" (https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html#angle)
I got some strange results like this:
[image]

Any idea why this happens?
I already have seen that there is the possibility to create a custom projection which allows to add rotation parameters, but I could not figure out how the correct usage is with using my own projection. Currently I am using (EPSG:25832)
([Defining coordinate reference system with rotation in GeoServer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159037/defining-coordinate-reference-system-with-rotation-in-geoserver))

Would be nice to find a solution to display the rotation without manipulating the raw NetCDF data.

Comment: please clarify what you are hoping to achieve with the rotation - I don't think that WMS angle does what you want

Comment: I think you need to ask a new question about why you can't use a rotated crs as outlined in the other question

Comment: thanks for the quick answer!
I will ask a new question how to add rotation parameters to grid_mapping attributes