# Defining rotated CRS with WKT

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver, affine-transformation

I am trying to figure out how to display a rotated grid correctly with GeoServer with using the affine transformation in WKT as described here:
[Defining coordinate reference system with rotation in GeoServer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159037/defining-coordinate-reference-system-with-rotation-in-geoserver)

I am getting the affine parameters by using the `Affine.rotation` function within Python. However the images is cropped and the georeferencing isn't correct afterwards.

Affine parameters used:

```
affine=Affine.rotation(58.0)# angle in degrees
elt_0_0=affine.a 
elt_0_1=affine.b 
elt_0_2=918079.626281209 #X Value of lower left Coordinate which is also the rotation point
elt_1_0=affine.d
elt_1_1=affine.e
elt_1_2=6445039.217828758 #Y Value of lower left Coordinate which is also the rotation point
```

Original Image:

[image: original image]

Current result with affine transformation:

[image: Current Result]

The Raster should be rotated like this with maintaining its actual size:

[image: desired result]

The lower left corner of this raster should have the coordinates as mentioned above and are already known. The Size of the "real" raster image (containing value data) should be maintained (2000m*1200m)

This is the currently used WKT String:

```
FITTED_CS["BPAF", 
  PARAM_MT["Affine",
    PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
    PARAMETER["num_col", 3], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_0",0.5299192642332049], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_1", -0.848048096156426], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_2", 918079.626281209], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_0", 0.848048096156426], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_1", 0.5299192642332049], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_2", 6445039.217828758]], 
  PROJCS["WGS84 / Google Mercator", 
    GEOGCS["WGS 84", 
      DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", 
        SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, 
          AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], 
      PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, 
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
       UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
       AXIS["Longitude", EAST], 
       AXIS["Latitude", NORTH], 
       AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]], 
    PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"], 
    PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6378137.0], 
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
    PARAMETER["central_meridian", 0.0], 
    PARAMETER["scale_factor", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["false_easting", 0.0], 
    PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0], 
    UNIT["m", 1.0], 
    AXIS["x", EAST],
    AXIS["y", NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","900913"]], 
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","8011113"]]
```

The Bounding Box Values had not been changed, the Lat/Lon Bounding Box coordinates are not correct whithout reprojection:

[image]

When declaring a reprojection from EPSG:8011113 to EPSG:900913 the Lat/Lon values are correct:

[image: Bounding Box with reprojection]

However, after the reprojection the raster can't be displayed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.1.1/WMS_exception_1_1_1.dtd"> <ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1" >   <ServiceException>
      java.io.IOException: Failed to create reader from file:data/NetCDF/test/test.nc and hints Hints:
  GRID_COVERAGE_FACTORY            = GridCoverageFactory                                                                                                               
    TILE_ENCODING                  = null                                                                                                                              
  STYLE_FACTORY                    = StyleFactoryImpl                                                                                                                  
  REPOSITORY                       = org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogRepository@89dd00                                                                                    
  FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER = true                                                                                                                              
  FORCE_AXIS_ORDER_HONORING        = http                                                                                                                              
  EXECUTOR_SERVICE                 = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@d14e79e[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
  FEATURE_FACTORY                  = org.geotools.feature.LenientFeatureFactoryImpl@3bfc6a5e                                                                           
  LENIENT_DATUM_SHIFT              = true                                                                                                                              
  COMPARISON_TOLERANCE             = 1.0E-8                                                                                                                            
  FILTER_FACTORY                   = FilterFactoryImpl                                                                                                                 

Failed to create reader from file:data/NetCDF/test/test.nc and hints Hints:
  GRID_COVERAGE_FACTORY            = GridCoverageFactory                                                                                                               
    TILE_ENCODING                  = null                                                                                                                              
  STYLE_FACTORY                    = StyleFactoryImpl                                                                                                                  
  REPOSITORY                       = org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogRepository@89dd00                                                                                    
  FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER = true                                                                                                                              
  FORCE_AXIS_ORDER_HONORING        = http                                                                                                                              
  EXECUTOR_SERVICE                 = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@d14e79e[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
  FEATURE_FACTORY                  = org.geotools.feature.LenientFeatureFactoryImpl@3bfc6a5e                                                                           
  LENIENT_DATUM_SHIFT              = true                                                                                                                              
  COMPARISON_TOLERANCE             = 1.0E-8                                                                                                                            
  FILTER_FACTORY                   = FilterFactoryImpl                                                                                                                 

</ServiceException></ServiceExceptionReport>
```

Comment: what did you set the bounding box to?

Comment: You mean in the geoserver Settings?
Native Bounding Box
Min X 918.079,625
Min Y 6.445.039
Max X 920.079,625
Max Y 6.446.239

Those Values refer to EPSG:900913

The Lat/Lon Bounding Box coordinates are not correct:
Min X -40,9167389547673
Min Y 37,139289543793076
Max X -40,898420235646235
Max Y 37,15598775147418

When declaring a reprojection from EPSG:8011113 to EPSG:900913
they are correct:
Min X 8,247249591762188
Min Y 49,99285762873216
Max X 8,265215897444577
Max Y 49,99978726994185
However afterwards the raster can't be displayed anymore

Comment: please use the [edit] button to update your question

Answer (score 0):

fixed by editing the code from this topic:
[Using customized Coordinate System in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83861/using-customized-coordinate-system-in-arcgis-desktop)

My used grid_mapping:

```
def addGridMappingVars(var,locationLat,locationLon,rotation):
    var.grid_mapping_name= "mercator"
    var.standard_parallel= 0.0
    var._CoordinateTransformType= "Projection"
    var._CoordinateAxisTypes= "GeoX GeoY"
    var.spatial_ref= 'PROJCS["Hotine_Oblique_Mercator_Azimuth_Center",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_unknown",SPHEROID["WGS84",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Hotine_Oblique_Mercator_Azimuth_Center"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",'+str(locationLat)+'],PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",'+str(locationLon)+'],PARAMETER["rectified_grid_angle",'+str(-rotation)+'],PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["m",1.0], AUTHORITY["EPSG","8011112"]]'
    return var
```

Comment: EPSG isn't the authority for a CRS with code 8011112.