# CRS rotation in Geoserver

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver, well-known-text, affine-transformation

I want to add rotation angle for a custom metric CRS, that I created before in the Geoserver. I tryed two methods:

1. Adding a WKT-stroke of rotated CRS to the Geoserver as usual. The example of such method is here: [Defining coordinate reference system with rotation in GeoServer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159037/defining-coordinate-reference-system-with-rotation-in-geoserver?rq=1)
   Geoserver accepted this WKT-stroke, however, vizualized data didn't rotate to the specified angle
2. Adding affine transformations for CRS as WKT stroke in epsg_operations.properties. I made everything as described in documentation https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/configuration/crshandling/coordtransforms.html#define-a-custom-coordinate-operation
   Initially there wasn't file epsg_operations.properties in user_projections folder (where epsg.properties file is located). So I created it and then added WKT stroke for affine transformation in accordance with the one that is in the Geoserver documentation

Where could I have made a mistake? Is there another method to rotate CRS in Geoserver?

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file. We also probably need to see the WKT you are using