# .prj (Srtext) to proj.4 for custom projection using local grid, error ' no translation for LOcal to proj.4 format is known'

Tags: qgis, proj, coordinate-system

I have to transform the local reference system with the following SRtext parameters:

```
PROJCS["Sagalassos Local Grid",
GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
DATUM["D_WGS_1984",
SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
PROJECTION["Local"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",2500.0],
PARAMETER["False_Northing",2500.0],
PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.0],
PARAMETER["Azimuth",0.0],
PARAMETER["Longitude_Of_Center",30.5200246520608],
PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Center",37.6767593942953],
UNIT["Meter",1.0]]');
```

If I try gdal to get the information, it gives me the error: `No translation for LOcal to proj.4 format is known`.

Comment: The Esri "Local" projection is actually orthographic on an ellipsoid versus sphere. Because it looks like the data's very large scale, try orthographic.

Comment: Yes I found in the documentation that it was "orthogonal grid" . How can I specify that in proj.4 txt?

Comment: Thanks . Yes I found in the documentation that it was "orthogonal grid" .

 I specified  in proj.4 txt as:+proj=ortho +lat_0= 37.6767593942953 +lon_0= 30.5200246520608  +x_0 2500.0 +y_0 2500.0 +ellps=WGS84  +units=m +no_defs

But how to make sure that i am doing it right?

Comment: This looks rather good, except that `x_0` and `y_0` lack an equal sign. Look at http://geotiff.maptools.org/proj_list/orthographic.html for the parameter definitions.

Answer (score 1):

`Local` is not an allowed value for a projection method.

It must be Mercator, Transverse Mercator, Stereographic or some other kind of known projection.

[Using customized Coordinate System in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83861/using-customized-coordinate-system-for-archaeological-site-data) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks . Yes I found in the documentation that it was "orthogonal grid" . I specified in proj.4 txt as:+proj=ortho +lat_0= 37.6767593942953 +lon_0= 30.5200246520608 +x_0 2500.0 +y_0 2500.0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs But how to make sure that i am doing it right?