# How to get the exact coordinates of Wolfcamp aquifer locations?

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, coordinates

I currently working on the data set ["Wolfcamp Aquifer"](https://rubenfcasal.github.io/npsp/reference/aquifer.html), but the coordinates in the data set is just a relative coordinates. So, is there anyone who has the original coordinates?

Comment: You may have to look into the sources given in http://wiki.stat.ucla.edu/socr/index.php/SOCR_061708_NC_Data_Aquifer

Comment: Thank you so much. I check the link and the reference but, unfortunately, it's still the relatively coordinates. I was wondering how can I get the exact coordinates if I randomly assign a reference point to the relative coordinates.

Comment: You would need the **exact** coordinates of the reference point to create a custom CRS like in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83861/using-customized-coordinate-system-in-arcgis-desktop . Note that map units have to be kilometers.

Comment: If you want to type in (or image-to-text) the numbers, they are in the appendix of this PDF: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236564521_Geostatistical_analysis_of_potentiometric_data_in_Wolfcamp_aquifer_of_the_Palo_Duro_Basin_Texas

Comment: I've OCRd and fixed it up: https://gitlab.com/snippets/1710174

Comment: The map from the data in the `geoR` package shows one point clearly not in the same place as the map from the paper. Whether there's a transcription error in the original map from the original data or from the data to geoR I do not yet know...

Answer (score 1):

I found a map of the locations in an  ICOTS8 (2010) Invited Paper by Harper & Clark called "AMARILLO BY MORNING: DATA VISUALIZATION IN GEOSTATISTICS" - you can probably search online and find this. I extracted the image, and georeferenced it in QGIS.

Then I identified a few of the sample locations on the map and got their lat-long coordinates. I then matched those up to the "relative" coordinates from the data set in R. So now I have a table of:

```
 x_lat y_lat x_relative y_relative
```

coordinates for seven of the points. I can then run `ogr2ogr` on the command line using the coordinate pairs as control points - it looks like this:

```
ogr2ogr \
 -tps \
 -gcp  -233.72172 -115.83894 -11636657   4003094 \
 -gcp -30.54492  115.72629 -11392916   4286809 \
 -gcp   133.79896   95.12698 -11190784   4260256 \
 -gcp   174.71182  -27.48198 -11143259   4107547 \
 -gcp   18.74859 -130.78953 -11331381   3985634 \
 -gcp   -29.96271  -37.89631 -11391316   4099389 \
 -gcp  169.09138   51.54656 -11147872   4205489 \
 -f "ESRI shapefile" wcreftps.shp wc.shp
```

On each `gcp` option, the first two numbers are the "relative" coordinates, and the second two are in EPSG:3857 (Google Mercator). `wc.shp` is the R data saved to a shapefile.

After running this, the shapefile `wcreftps.shp` seems geolocated correctly - here it is with an OpenStreetMap and county boundaries.

[image]

The coordinates, in the same order as the 85 coordinates in the `wolfcamp` object in the R `geoR` package, are in this pastebin:

https://pastebin.com/zdXMdnZ7

Caveat: These coordinates are as precise as my clicking on the map - they are not the original measured coordinates but should be close enough for most purposes that use the whole map - don't zoom in on one point and expect to see the exact location.

Comment: Wow...................Thank you so much .............It's amazing..I'm new to this field, your answer is really helpful.

Comment: I think I need to learn QGIS now.

Comment: I may try and compare the coordinates I got from this with the ones I got from the original paper (linked in my comment to the question).

Comment: I think they didn't give the exact coordinates in their original paper, right?

Comment: The paper I link in the comments gives both lat-long and offset-in-miles from a point coordinates. I'm not sure how "exact" these coordinates are, plus the lat-long appear to be in a 1958 military coordinate system and I can't find the technical manual online so I don't exactly know the coordinate transform parameters to get from that to EPSG:4326.

Comment: And I've now completed OCRing and correcting the "relative" coordinates from the paper and there is definitely a wrong location point in the `geoR` data set. Once I've tidied things up I might report it.

Comment: @Spacedman I get rather good results with `+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-102 +datum=NAD83 +x_0=0 +y_0=-3696553 +k=0.9996 +units=us-mi +no_defs` except for point `ROO-014` which is off by -2,29437 miles in x. Might be a typo.

Comment: There's definitely one point, the 49th, that is *way* off in the geoR dataset compared to the data in the paper. In the wrong county.

Comment: @Spacedman, so the coordinates you post is the right one?

Comment: Yes, I think so.